# Is there such a thing like sass mixins in react?

Tags: reactjs, routes, components, jsx

So I have a react application that involves a lot of routing and this routings are done based on conditions. For example if a user logs in then some of the paths might mean something different than what they would mean if the user wasn't logged in. Here is a simple example.

```
<Switch>
(this.state.isAuthenticated)?
    this.state.game?
        <Route path="/game/Game91" render={(props) => <Game91 {...props} games={this.state.allGames} />} />:
        <Route path="/game/Game91/" render={(props) => <CreateGame {...props} game="game91" />} />:
    <Route  exact path="/game/Game91" render={(props) => <LoginForm {...props} onGuestLogin = {this.guestLogin} parentLocation = "/game/Game91" />} /> 
    
    
}
</Switch>
...
```

So in the above code if a user is authenticated and if the game is choosen then I want the url `/game/Game91` to take the user to the Game91 component. If the user is authenticated but a game isnt choosen I want `/game/Game91` to take the user to the create game component and so forth. And this has been workign for me for now. I unserstand this might not be the best practice out their, so I would be glad if you share what the best practices are in such scinarios and send me links to more reads. But my main question for now is that what if I have another path like `/somepath/to` that also means different things like the `/game/Game91`. To do, that I will have to rewrite all the above code since I can't fit all this in one ternary operator. Hypotetically this is what I would like.

```
<Switch>
(this.state.isAuthenticated)?
    this.state.game?
        <Route path="/game/Game91" render={..something..} />
        <Route path="/somePath/to" render={..something..} />
        :
        <Route path="/game/Game91" render={..somethingElse..} />
        <Route path="/somePath/to" render={..somethingElse..} />            
        :
        <Route path="/game/Game91" render={..something..} />
        <Route path="/somePath/to" render={..something..} />


}
</Switch>
```

But the above isn't possible because a ternary operators can't return more than one thing. and I cant use if statments beacuse JSX doesn't allow them. So ideally if I could have function that will return this pair of things without wrapping them in any kind of container like you would with scss mixins that would be great. So is there such a thing in react or are there other better ways to do such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally every page or container should be addressed to only one route path. Instead of changing the component at runtime by checking the flags, you can navigate from one route to another based on your conditions using react hooks.

Note:

This example uses react router v6. If you are using the v5.2 version of react router, then you need to use history api instead of navigate.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        if(isGameActive)
            navigate('/gaming');
        else
            navigate('/create-game');
    }
    else {
        navigate('/login');
    }
}, [isAuthenticated]);

<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/gaming" element={<Game91 />} />
    <Route path="/create-game" element={<CreateGaming />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

[react-router v6](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-router-v6/)

Comment: Thanks. so is this the accepted practice. I will read more about hooks. but a quick question is userEffect a component cycle method.

Comment: import {useEffect } from 'react';  useEffect is a hook in react 16. Component lifecycles usage comes to an end with react hooks for functional components. A hook replaces a component lifecycle function based on conditions.

Comment: BTW how were things like this done before react hooks.

Comment: If you think you dont want to use react hooks, we can use history.push inside componentWillReceiveProps, and check for the flag changes and trigger navigation to other pages.  example :  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-access-the-history-object-outside-of-components

Comment: Hi again, I was looking into this and one problem I noticed is that if I implement this with history.push, the user can actually type the url '/gaming' and have acces to it without actually being authenticated. Is there a nice way to prevent that. Do hooks handle that for you.

Comment: For direct launch scenario, to validate the user, we need to pass a prop to the component, <Game91 userProps={{ isAuthenticated }} /> , and if the prop is false, the Game91 component will have to handle unAuthenticated users by pushing to home route.